# Apache mod_rewrite links proxy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make a proxy for external links with apache's mod_rewrite module.
I want it to redirect user from, ie `http://stackoverflow.com/go/http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/` where `http://stackoverflow.com/` is my site's URL. So I added a rule to `.htaccess` file.

`RewriteRule ^/go/http://(.+)  http://$1 [R=302,L]`

But it doesn't work at all. How to fix this?

Comment: What is that `~` character doing there? In .htaccess, the regex must not start with /

Comment: Sorry, it was really odd. But this changed nothing, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if Apache or the browser reduces `//` to `/`, but since it doesn't change the directory one of them reduces this to a single slash on my setup. That's why the second slash has a `?` behind it in the rule below:

```
RewriteRule ^go/http://?(.*)$ http://$1 [R,L]
```

This will redirect the user to that domain.

Answer (score 0):

This will rewrite all urls (without the beginning http://) to new complete URL. If you're gonna use https links also, you need something like the second rule.

```
RewriteRule ^go/(.*) http://$1 [R=302,L,QSA,NE]
RewriteRule ^gos/(.*) https://$1 [R=302,L,QSA,NE]
```

I also added the QSA if your need to include parameters

Comment: In per-directory context, which .htaccess is, the path name is included in the prefix, which is stripped from the matchable url. In other words `^/` will **never match**.

Comment: Besides that, this will try to redirect to a path on the current server rather than a custom domain.

Comment: Fixed it. Runs on my server now: `http://www.malmanger.no/go/stackoverflow.com/questions/25223159/apache-mod-rewrite-links-proxy/25223217` wil link back to this page ;-)